# Как сделать ссылку или кнопку на Андройде

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Получаю с сервера данные, вывожу в `ScrollView`. Как сделать по окончанию прокрутки кнопку или ссылку "подробнее", что бы можно было повесить `onClickListener`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48514736/1991579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить слушателя прокрутки:

```
   scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
       .addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (scrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom()
                     <= (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) {
                    //scroll view is at bottom
                    //show your button
                } else {
                    //scroll view is not at bottom
                    //hide your button
                }
            }
        });
```

или

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
        // bottom of scroll view
        //show your button
    }
    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
       // top of scroll view
       //hide your button
    }
}
```